# Rendering firestore values in Vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a simple app and am running into trouble getting Vue rendering data I'm trying to pull from Firestore. Below is the code for a vue page after someone logs in. Essentially I'm just trying to get it to display the name of the person who logged in. Currently I have each user's display name as the document ID for the get() function. Right now, it doesn't even seem like its running the 'firestore()' function since I tried outputting some text to the console at the beginning but I didn't see it. Any idea what's happening here? Thank you!

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs12 class="text-xs-center" mt-5>
        <h1>Home page</h1>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12 class="text-xs-center" mt-3>
        <p>Welcome {{ name }}</p>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      name: ''
    }
  },
  firestore () {
    firebase.firestore().collection('user').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName).get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (doc) {
        var data = doc.data()
        return {
          name: data.name
        }
      } else {
        console.log('No document exists')
      }
    }).catch(error => { console.log('Error: ' + error) })
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `created` hook for this purpose.

```
created() {
  firebase.firestore().collection('user').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName).get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (doc) {
        var data = doc.data()
        this.name = data.name
      } else {
        console.log('No document exists')
      }
    }).catch(error => { console.log('Error: ' + error) })
}
```

If you're using [vuefire](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire), you can do

```
firestore: {
  users: firebase.firestore().collection('user').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName)
}
```

then use `this.users` in your Vue code

Comment: Thanks! I installed Vuefire and the function seems to be running, but it still doesn't seem to be binding the "name" value onto the "name" attribute in the data function. I console logged the "data.name" and it's getting the right output, but for some reason just isn't getting attached to the variable in data (). Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using `created` hook? Please post your updated code.